# How to validate image file before uploading in php?

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file where i want to allow only png files.For validation, i would check wether extension of file is `.png` or not. But in my case if user changes the file extension from gif to png then how to validate image before uploading in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow this
http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php

you will find the way

exif_imagetype() reads the first bytes of an image and checks its signature.

```
<?php
if (exif_imagetype('image.gif') != IMAGETYPE_GIF) {
    echo 'The picture is not a gif';
}
?>
```